# twitter-bootstrap center carousel image reguardless of screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following desires for a twitter bootstrap carousel:

1. When screen is bigger then carousel, I want the image centered.
2. When the screen is smaller than the carousel, I want to see just PART of the image. This part of the image should be centered.
3. At no point should the images be resized or scaled
4. The transitions should work.

My example below fixed problems 1-3.. but it breaks 4.  I can easily fix 4 if I am willing to break 3, but that is no good.

Bootply link to example: http://bootply.com/88542

HTML:

```
<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/abstract/1" height="600px" width="1200px">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Bootstrap 3 Carousel Layout</h1>
          <pthis is="" an="" example="" layout="" with="" carousel="" that="" uses="" the="" bootstrap="" 3="" styles.<="" small=""><p></p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://getbootstrap.com">Learn More</a>
        </p></pthis></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/abstract/2" height="600px" width="1200px">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Changes to the Grid</h1>
          <p>Bootstrap 3 still features a 12-column grid, but many of the CSS class names have completely changed.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200X600" height="600px" width="1200px">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Percentage-based sizing</h1>
          <p>With "mobile-first" there is now only one percentage-based grid.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>  
</div>
<!-- /.carousel -->
```

CSS

```
/* BOOTSTRAP 3.x GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
body {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}



/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 600px;
  width: 1200px;
  background-color:#bbb;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -600px;
}
.carousel img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}



/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  /* Remve the edge padding needed for mobile */
  .marketing {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }

  /* Navbar positioning foo */
  .navbar-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: -90px; /* Negative margin to pull up carousel. 90px is roughly margins and height of navbar. */
  }
  /* The navbar becomes detached from the top, so we round the corners */
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  /* Bump up size of carousel content */
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 11):

This might help if you want the image to be re-sized according to the screen size of the device. The `width = "100%"` will do the job.

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/abstract/2" width = "100%">
```

Answer (score 5):

just add this to your css:

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add this

```
.carousel .item img {
   left: -9999px;  /*important */
   right: -9999px;  /*important */
   margin: 0 auto;  /*important */
   max-width: none;  /*important */
   min-width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
}
```

And of course one of the parent divs needs to have a position:relative, but I believe it does by default.

See it here: http://paginacrestinului.ro/

Comment: Make also `min-width: None` for a very nice always centered, not stretched images. thank you @AdiCumpanasu